# Is there a way to configure throttling for callbacks in WCF?

Tags: wcf, callback, throttling

Is it possible to control throttling on callback? So the server would be limited(controlled) how often it can callback the client.

Answer (score 0):

yes.. there is a way you can define the max limit of users...
you can add max no of concurrent calls, instances and sessions.

Sample config...

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="Throttling">
                    <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="2" maxConcurrentInstances="2" />
                    <serviceThrottling />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I was asking about the callback method, i don't think instances, sessions, users make any sense for a callback.